# pyinstaller does not include nodejs in build

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, pyinstaller

I am using the following codes on the editor without compiling, but when I try to run them after compiling using pyinstaller, they give me an error.

How do I get pyinstaller to include nodejs in the build?

**My code:**

```
from javascript import require
print(require)
```

**Uncompiled editor output:**

```
<function require at 0x01F1B460>
```

**Compiled exe output:**

```
[JSE] node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1080
[JSE]   throw err;
[JSE]   ^
[JSE]
[JSE] Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\fatih\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI164682\javascript\js\bridge.js'
[JSE]     at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1077:15)
[JSE]     at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:922:27)
[JSE]     at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
[JSE]     at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47 {
[JSE]   code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
[JSE]   requireStack: []
[JSE] }
[JSE]
[JSE] Node.js v18.17.0

** The Node process has crashed. Please restart the runtime to use JS APIs. **

Timed out get 0 needsNodePatches None
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sab.py", line 1, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 385, in exec_module
  File "javascript\__init__.py", line 20, in <module>
  File "javascript\__init__.py", line 16, in init
  File "javascript\proxy.py", line 225, in __getattr__
  File "javascript\proxy.py", line 145, in getProp
  File "javascript\proxy.py", line 38, in ipc
Exception: Timed out accessing 'needsNodePatches'
[17348] Failed to execute script 'sab' due to unhandled exception!
```

Comment: When using pyinstaller, can you include all the flags and params you are using?

Comment: im only using --onefile